# rollapply with zoo and sub-daily data

Tags: r, time-series, zoo, rollapply

I have a dataset with unequally spaced observations and frequently observations occur more than once per day.  I'd like to apply a function to windows of my data, but I want the windows to be defined by time rather than by row.  For example, I'd like to compute the mean for days 1-5, days 2-6, etc. within my dataset, and days 1-5 may correspond to rows 1-13, days 2-6 corresponds to rows 3-18, etc.

I saw that the `rollapply` function accepts `zoo` objects, and I assumed it would work as I describe above (i.e. applying the function over windows defined by time rather than windows defined by rows).  However, this doesn't seem to be the case:

```
my.ts = zoo( 1:100, as.Date("201401","%Y%j")+1:100 )
mean1 = rollapply( my.ts, 3, mean, align="right" )
my.ts = zoo( 1:100, as.Date("201401","%Y%j")+1:100/2 )
mean2 = rollapply( my.ts, 3, mean, align="right" )
all( mean1==mean2 )
```

I'd expect `mean2` to be different from `mean1` since `mean2` has two observations per day instead of one.  However, it appears that `rollapply` uses rows to define the windows rather than the times from the `zoo` object.  Is there a work-around for this?  Or, possibly some other function I should be using in place of `rollapply`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`rollapply` is documented in `?rollapply` so there is no need to guess how it works.

To do what you want fill in the missing days with NAs and then perform the mean.  For example, to do a mean for every three days rather than every three observations:

```
library(zoo)

# test data
tt <- as.Date("2000-01-01") + c(1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8, 10)
z <- zoo(seq_along(tt), tt)

# fill it out to a daily series, zm, using NAs
g <- zoo(, seq(start(z), end(z), "day")) # zero width zoo series on a grid
zm <- merge(z, g)

rollapply(zm, 3, mean, na.rm = TRUE, fill = NA)
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  I think you may be misunderstanding my problem though...  I have multiple observations per day, and sometimes differing amounts.  I want rollapply to compute means for every three days and use all the observations that occur within those three days.

Comment: If your data is hourly then create a regular hourly series and take the same approach.  If its by the minute make a regular minute by minute series, etc.   Please provide representative data in the future to better communicate what you want.

Comment: Ah, I see, ok.  So, if I have observations irregularly spaced throughout a day, I need to break the day into chunks and add in NA's for chunks without observations.  Thanks!